# Spring Boot application suddenly stopped connecting to my MongoDB database and is connecting to the test database by default

Tags: angular, database, mongodb, spring-boot, default

I have a Spring Boot application that was working perfectly until recently when it suddenly stopped connecting to my MongoDB database. The code hasn't been changed and was previously able to connect to the database without any issues.

When I run the application, I can see in the logs that it's connecting to the MongoDB server, but it's not able to find the default database where my data is stored. I've double-checked my database configuration settings, but everything looks fine.

One thing I've noticed is that the logs show that my data is being stored in a test database by default, but I'm not sure if this is related to the issue. I've tried changing the database name in the configuration settings to match the test database, but it still doesn't work.

I've tried restarting the MongoDB server and my application, but the issue persists. I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

And i've also tried checking if my database exist with mongoshell and it s there , i even added a new collection with mongo shell and it worked there

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on what else I can do to resolve this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you need to share some piece of code that you used to connect to db, it could be anyting, wrong configuration, mistype ....